# Can not find crash dump for PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, linux, ubuntu, phantomjs

Here is what I've done:

- Downloaded and unarchived phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2 binary version from official website
- Moved it like `mv phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64 /usr/local/share`
- Created link to main bin file:

  `sudo ln -sf /usr/local/share/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/bin`

It works with a js file, at some random point crashes with message:

```
PhantomJS has crashed. Please read the bug reporting guide at
and file a bug report
```

Neither in `/tmp` nor in script's folder, I can't find crash dump.

Where are crash dumps in Ubuntu 16.10?

Or how to enable dumping?

OS: Ubuntu 16.10 64 Bit Server
PhantomJS version: 2.1.1

Comment: you mean referring to the kernel crash core dump?

Answer (score 0):

The core dump is written in the current directory of the process at the time of the crash.

Off course, core dumps need to be enabled, by default those are usually disabled. Check the output of `ulimit -c`, if that's 0 then no core file will be written.

How to enable core dump?

Run `ulimit -c unlimited` to enable core dumps; this is a per-process setting which is inherited by processes started by that process.

Your question is very generic: I dont is this what you want?

[More info about enabling core dump.](http://en.linuxreviews.org/HOWTO_enable_core-dumps)

The kernel crash dump utility is installed with the following command:

```
sudo apt install linux-crashdump.
```

[You can follow this confiugration guide.](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/kernel-crash-dump.html)

Comment: it didn't help me. Can't find dump still

Comment: havey you rebooted the system after setting the ulimit?